# Why does this PHP regular expression return 1?

Tags: php, regex

Why does the following regular function call return a value of `1`:

```
preg_match('<strong>', '<strong[\>\s]+')
```

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), I would have thought they ought to be reversed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<strong>` is a regular expression with [angle brackets as delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The actual regex is just the `strong` part, which successfully matches against the subject string since it has no `^` and `$` anchors.

This will fail:

```
preg_match('/<strong>/', '<strong[\>\s]+')
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I didn't know `<` and `>` could be used as delimiters. Here are some more: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Can you confirm whether the pattern `<strong>` and `/strong/` can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, `<strong>` and `/strong/` are interchangeable in PCRE.  In the first instance the delimiters are `<` and `>` and in the second instance the delimiters are `/` and `/`.  Other than that they are identical.  The reason for allowing different delimiters is just for readability; if you use `/` then you have to escape all the `/` in your pattern (which isn't the best for, say, matching URLs or file paths).